# Why is assert defined as (void)0?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, no-op

Why
 `#define assert(expression) ((void)0)`,
rather than
 `#define assert(expression)`
is used in release mode?(strictly speaking, when NDEBUG is defined)

I heard that there are some reasons, but I've forgot it.

Comment: There is usually a `;` afterwards, and if assert became nothing, that lonely remaining `;` might trigger a warning.

Comment: The latter would allow `assert(true)` (without semicolon), whereas the former wouldn't.

Comment: @MarcGlisse you should post it as an answer. For now, your comment is the only statement that actually answers the poster's question.

Answer (score 4):

`((void)0)` defines `assert(expression)` to do nothing.
The main reason to use it is that `#define assert(expression)` would allow `assert(expression)` to compile without a semicolon but it will not compile if the macro is defined as `((void)0)`

Comment: And what is the difference with `#define assert(expr)`?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `((void)0)` is used in `empty macros` is make them behave like a function, in the sense that you need to specify the semicolon `;` at the end

For example:

```
#define assert1(expression) (void)0
     assert(1) // compile error, missing ;

#define assert2(expression) 
     assert(1) // works
```