# Why the definition of the assert macro, in a release build, cannot be just `#define assert(expression) 0`?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, assert

This is the definition of the assert macro in Visual Studio 2019

```
#ifdef NDEBUG

    #define assert(expression) ((void)0)

#else

    _ACRTIMP void __cdecl _wassert(
        _In_z_ wchar_t const* _Message,
        _In_z_ wchar_t const* _File,
        _In_   unsigned       _Line
        );

    #define assert(expression) (void)(                                                       \
            (!!(expression)) ||                                                              \
            (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) \
        )

#endif
```

As you can see above, the definition of the macro assert in a release build is

```
#define assert(expression) ((void)0)
```

Why can't it be just `#define assert(expression) 0` ?

Comment: Related: [Why is assert is defined as (void)0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329271/why-is-assert-is-defined-as-void0). (Not a duplicate as it focuses on another alternative, but it might be of interest to people finding this question in the future.)

Comment: @JaMiT I was not convinced by the answers given in the linked question. So I decided to  ask the same question in [Visual C++](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc439bc5-8547-41fa-9d26-cb9e5dff6ed0/why-does-the-assert-macro-has-to-expand-to-void0-in-a-release-build?forum=vcgeneral). And I got a brilliant answer by Igor Tandetnik there.

Comment: * shrug * Igor does give a nice example there. However, you might note that somewhere on this page (to the right in wide browsers, towards the bottom in narrow) there is now a "Linked" section with a link to *"Why is assert defined as (void)0?"*. I can add a related SO question to that section by adding a comment. Adding a related non-SO question is not so simple. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This prevents using `assert` as an expression. So if one does (by mistake):

```
a = assert(something);
```

The compiler will throw an error both for a release and debug build.

Comment: It took me a while to accept what you said. But your answer  is the correct one. Great answer by the way!

Comment: @Belloc There isn't necessarily a single "correct" answer; there can be multiple reasons.  Also, this answer is slightly inaccurate.  The `(void)` cast prevents `assert()` from being an *rvalue*, but it still could be used as an *expression*.  For example: `condition ? assert(something) : assert(somethingElse)` or `assert(condition), puts("hello")`.

Comment: @jamesdlin You'll find the reason I accepted Julien's answer instead of yours [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a98afe72577f244). Basically, Julien's answer appears to better explain this example, as there is no warning in this case. I also noticed the small inaccuracy in Julien's answer. But that was a very small issue in my judgement, to not decide in his favor.

Answer (score 2):

Some compilers might want the `(void)` cast to suppress warnings about an expression whose value isn't used.